# What is the mechanism for equilibration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I read on page 5 of Matthew Schwartz' book QFT & the SM that if you heat a box with monochromatic light, then (later) all the frequencies will get excited. The author says that particles have to be created and destroyed to accomplish this. This must show the need for QFT.

I'm just wondering if I will eventually see a mechanism by which equilibration is accomplished or if I will see only a calculation that gives the correct result without an underlying mechanism. This is not to say that a calculation would not be a great thing but I want to know if there's a mechanism.

Comment: I think that this was just introduced to show the need for a theory where particle number isn't necessarily conserved...

Comment: If you are really interested in finding equilibrating mechanisms, [these lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0409233) are a good start. Non-equilibrium QFT is a very young and dynamic field where many discoveries may yet await us, but it is amazing that many equilibrating processes can be understood through the next-to-leading order in the $\frac{1}{N}$-expansion of theories with a $\mathrm{O}(N)$ symmetry.